# How to create a summary list in xslt?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have a problem with creating an XSLT template for an HTML table. I have the following XML data, and I need to create a summary it.

```
<doc-number>1</doc-number>
<book>Gardening/John Smith</book>
<call-no>B-1</call-no>

<doc-number>1</doc-number>
<book>Gardening/John Smith</book>
<call-no>B-1/23</call-no>

<doc-number>1</doc-number>
<book>Forest/Ema Who</book>
<call-no>A-1/2</call-no>

<doc-number>1</doc-number>
<book>Gardening/John Smith</book>
<call-no>B-1/5</call-no>
```

I need this:

```
Items  Book
3 Gardening/John Smith         
1 Forest/Ema Who
```

I think it might work function of current-grouping-key, but I can not apply it. Have you any idea?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**XML:**

```
<root>
    <doc-number>1</doc-number>
    <book>Gardening/John Smith</book>
    <call-no>B-1</call-no>

    <doc-number>1</doc-number>
    <book>Gardening/John Smith</book>
    <call-no>B-1/23</call-no>

    <doc-number>1</doc-number>
    <book>Forest/Ema Who</book>
    <call-no>A-1/2</call-no>

    <doc-number>1</doc-number>
    <book>Gardening/John Smith</book>
    <call-no>B-1/5</call-no>
</root>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:text>Items&#160;&#160;&#160;Books&#10;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="book" group-by=".">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())"/>&#160;&#160;&#160;<xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
Items   Books
3   Gardening/John Smith
1   Forest/Ema Who
```